# Update atm balance

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying make the make current balance method update its balance after a withdrawal method is called so that it becomes the starting balance for any subsequent withdrawal.I don't know what i'm doing wrong.Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class Customer
{
    private double deposit;
    private double balance;
    static double bankCharge = 0.50;



    public Customer(double depo)
    {
        if (depo > 2000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("deposit cannot be morethan 2000");
        }
        else
        {

            this.deposit += depo;
        }

    }

    public void setDeposit(double depo)
    {
        if (depo > 2000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, you cannot deposit morethan 2000");
        }
        else
        {
            this.deposit+= depo;
        }
    }

    public double currentBalance()
    {
        this.balance= this.deposit;
        //this.balance+=this.balance;

        return this.balance;
    }

    public double Withdrawal()
    {
        int amount;
        bool passed;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How much do you want to withdraw?");

            passed = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount);
            if ((!passed) || (amount % 5 != 0))

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong input,No decimals please,Enter in multiples of 5, Try again");

            }
        } while (!passed || amount % 5 != 0);

        double charges = amount + bankCharge; // amount to be withdrawn + the bank charge
        Console.WriteLine("charges are {0}", charges);
       // Console.WriteLine("Your current balance is {0}", this.currentBalance());
        if (charges > this.currentBalance())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you do not have enough money to perform this transaction");
        }
        else
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Your current balance is {0}", this.balance);
        this.balance-= charges; // withdrawal done
         Console.WriteLine(" balance after transaction/charges is={0} ",this.balance);
        }

        return this.balance;

    }




}





class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Customer lee = new Customer(500);
        lee.setDeposit(2000);
        lee.setDeposit(400);

        //Console.WriteLine("the withdraw function returns this amount {0}", lee.Withdrawal());
        Console.WriteLine(lee.Withdrawal());
        Console.WriteLine(lee.currentBalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we don't know what you're doing wrong either, because you haven't told us what is happening that you don't like.

Comment: As seen in Main,the current balance in 2900. lets say i want to withdraw 40, after the withdrawal, the withdrawal method returns 2859.5 which is correct because of  the 0.50 bank charge. The problem is: when i call the withdrawal function again instead of current  balance starting at 2859.5 it starts at the 2900. In other words, i want every time the withdrawal method is called by the customer, the starting balance should be the the balance returned by the withdrawal method from the last transaction.

Comment: Don't include substantive details in the comments area.  Modify your question to make it clear what you're asking.  Currently, it's not clear what's wrong by your question, and it will probably be closed.

Comment: What is `this.balance= this.deposit;` for in `currentBalance()`? Why Do you have `deposit` and `balance` in the first place (not only one of them)?

Comment: this.deposit initializes this.balance as its initial balance.Every time a deposit is made, this.balance is updated.But the issue i'm having is that every time a withdrawal is made, the withdrawal method returns exactly what the current balance should be.But when i call the withdrawal method again to withdraw money, this.balance does not update or retain the ending balance from the last transaction.

Comment: I'm just going to work on it again and change my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Code is now working the way i want it.I got rid of the implementation in currentBalance method.I set  this.balance to deposit in the constructor and setDeposit method which updates balance every time a deposit is made.Balance equally updates every time the withdrawal method is called and withdrawal is made.That was my initial challenge;balance didn't update after withdrawal.It is fixed now.You may close.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class Customer
{
    private double deposit;
    private double balance;
    static double bankCharge = 0.50;
    public Customer(double depo)
    {
        if (depo > 2000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("deposit cannot be morethan 2000");
        }
        else
        {

            this.deposit += depo;
            this.balance = this.deposit;
        }

    }
    public void setDeposit(double depo)
    {
        if (depo > 2000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, you cannot deposit morethan 2000");
        }
        else
        {
            this.deposit += depo;
            this.balance = this.deposit;
        }
    }

    public double currentBalance()
    {          
     return this.balance;
    }

    public double Withdrawal()
    {

        int amount;
        bool passed;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How much do you want to withdraw?");

            passed = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount);
            if ((!passed) || (amount % 5 != 0))

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong input,No decimals please,Enter in multiples of 5, Try again");

            }
        } while (!passed || amount % 5 != 0);

        double charges = amount + bankCharge;
        Console.WriteLine("charges are {0}", charges);
        Console.WriteLine("Your current balance is {0}", this.balance);
        if (charges > this.balance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you do not have enough money to perform this transaction");
        }
        else
        {

            this.balance = this.balance - charges;

        }

        return this.balance;
    }

}
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Customer lee = new Customer(500);
        lee.setDeposit(2000);
        lee.setDeposit(400);
        lee.setDeposit(250);
        lee.setDeposit(1850);
        // Console.WriteLine( lee.Withdrawal());
        //Console.WriteLine(lee.Withdrawal());
        Console.WriteLine("Balance before withdawal is {0}", lee.currentBalance());
        Console.WriteLine( " Your balance after withdawal is {0}",lee.Withdrawal());
        Console.WriteLine("Starting balance for next transaction is {0}",lee.currentBalance());
        Console.WriteLine("*******************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Balance before withdawal is {0}", lee.currentBalance());
        Console.WriteLine(" Your balance after withdawal is {0}", lee.Withdrawal());
        Console.WriteLine("Starting balance for next transaction is {0}", lee.currentBalance());

    }
}
```